# How to highlight invalid input only after submit with css and html5

Tags: css, html

I have input like:

```
<input type="email" required>
```

So it has html validation for email and emptiness. With css selector `:invalid` I can style it how I want, but this style will be implement immediately and I need it only after submiting, so how to do this anly after submit with html5 and css?

Comment: hi look at this code https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/eLvlf

Comment: @Mr.X hi, good example, but it creates an extra block with errors in it, the same effect has the html 5 validation with tooltips and without any js. It doesn't solve the problem